# how to Post request base64 encoded Audio blob to Node Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blob

Currently I have an Audio Blob that I converted to base64 so I can send it using post request to express js route.

**index.js**

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(AudioBLOB); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
   var base64data = reader.result;
   console.log(base64data.length);

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', "/", true);
   xhr.send("basecode64=" + base64data);
}
```

and in the express js route.

**routes/root.js**

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.query) // or req.params or req.body
}
```

How can I get the value of basecoe64?

Comment: Why not just post the blob as a blob?

Comment: You're adding ~34% overhead in size, not to mention the waste by going to/from base64.  Post binary data instead.